# Add boundary around the web page

Tags: html, css

I want to add boundaries around four sides of the web pages(black color 25px width). Now it is not lucky.

Please see my jsfiddle at [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/CenND/3/)

The partial css:

```
body {
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 25px;
padding: 0;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Why down vote? Give me a reason please....

Comment: I understand the downvote, you posted only partial code for your problem, it would have been better for us if you posted a more complete example, not your entire page code, but some HTML as well as the CSS related to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take away the background and margin from the body element and add stuff to the HTML element instead:

```
* { /*this * selector selects every element*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    background: #000;
    padding: 25px;
}

body {
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

(also use `box-sizing: border-box;` on everything to not screw stuff up with margins and padding)

http://jsfiddle.net/CenND/4/

---

I also removed `position: absolute;` from the footer. Now it behaves.

Comment: * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}, I meant the first code. * means all? And I found if I remove position: ablsolute; then everything is fine. No need to change other parts.